object of type 'function' has no len() in django
I use the Django 4 book to learn Django, but I get errors during pagination
TypeError at /blog/
object of type 'function' has no len()
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404
from .models import Post
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    # Pagination with 3 posts per page
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 3)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts': posts})

paginations.html file
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
{% if page.has_previous %}
<a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
{% endif %}

  <span class="current">
   <p>Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.</p> 
    </span>
    {% if page.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
    </div>


Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

You are paginating the view function, not the queryset, you should use posts instead of post_list:
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    # Pagination with 3 posts per page
    paginator = Paginator(post, 3)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})
in the template, the page object is named posts, so:
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
  {% if posts.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
  {% endif %}
  </span>
  <p>
    <span class="step-links">Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
  </p>
  {% if posts.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>

This code worked, thank you, but the previous code on GitHub https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-4-by-example/blob/main/Chapter02/mysite/blog/templates/pagination.html
There is and it works

@امیرحمزهباقری: it works if you use {'page': posts} in the render(..) call.
